# PHP, post variable over url

Tags: php, parsing

```
<?php
    echo "<a href='display_emp.php?employee_id=$rs['emp_id']; onClick=\"return confirm('Are you  that you` `want to DELETE this Data?')\" ><FONT COLOR='#F00'>Click To Delete</FONT></a>";
?>
```

`error: Parse error: parse error, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING'`

I am newbie in PHP, can anyone teach me how to solve this error?
thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
echo "<a href='display_emp.php?employee_id=".$rs['emp_id']."' onClick='return confirm(\"Are you  that you want to DELETE this Data?\")' ><FONT COLOR='#F00'>Click To Delete</FONT></a>";
```

Let me just say: that is some terrible html your using there...FONT...really??

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the quotes surrounding emp_id ($rs[emp_id])

```
echo "<a href='display_emp.php?employee_id=$rs[emp_id]; onClick=\"return confirm('Are you that you want to DELETE this Data?')\" ><FONT COLOR='#F00'>Click To Delete</FONT></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the double quotes (") inside your string, this makes the string end prematurely and that causes the error.

```
onClick=\"return
```

That's your problem

Comment: But it's escaped, so shouldn't that be valid?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
echo "<a href=\"display_emp.php?employee_id=" . $rs['emp_id'] . "\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you  that you want to DELETE this Data?');\"><FONT COLOR=\"#FF0000\">Click To Delete</FONT></a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're putting an array-variable with alphabetic index, you should not use another quote.

Here, this one will be correct:

```
echo "<a href='display_emp.php?employee_id=$rs[emp_id];' onClick=\"return confirm('Are you  that you` `want to DELETE this Data?')\" ><FONT COLOR='#F00'>Click To Delete</FONT></a>";
```

or as Sammaye suggested, concatenate different parts of strings.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution

```
$test = $rs['emp_id'];
$msg = "Are you  that you want to DELETE this Data?";
echo "<a href=display_emp.php?employee_id=".$test." onClick='return confirm(\"".$msg."\")' ><FONT COLOR='#F00'>Click To Delete</FONT></a>";
```